# How to underline active webpage in drop down menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a webpage using bootstrap and in my navigation bar, I have three drop down menus. I want to program the page so that the currently loaded page and its corresponding drop down menu are underlined or highlighted so that the user knows which page they are on.

In my html file, the drop down menu navbar is as follows:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="#'>item1</li>
     <li><a href='#'>item2</li>
</ul>
```

And in my css file, the activePage class is defined as follows:

```
.activePage {
     text-decoration: underline;
}
```

In my javascript file, I have tried to do the following:

```
$('.dropdown-menu a').click(function(){
     $('.dropdown-menu a').removeClass('activePage');
     $(this).addClass('activePage');
});
```

However the above does not underline the current page I am on in the drop down menu. I find it peculiar because when I do the following:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a class="activePage" href="#'>item1</li>
     <li><a href='#'>item2</li>
</ul>
```

The first item is successfully underlined.

Comment: Typo? `.a` should be `a`, It's not a class, but an element.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However, after changing it, it still didn't work.

Comment: You really just have some more typos in your code. See http://jsfiddle.net/00c20g0g/ with corrected typos; your JS code is correct. Please use an editor with proper syntax highlighting for HTML, it will make your life easier.

Comment: Thank you guys so much, it's fixed. I found that the bug was a mix of typos and not adding href="#" in the <a> tags. I put href="" instead, which also contributed to the no underline issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have some typing mistakes. The JavaScript should use `'.dropdown-menu a'` selector instead of `'.dropdown-menu .a'`. It was also missing a trailing paranthesis.

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNzRJP

html

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">item1</li>
  <li><a href="#">item2</li>
</ul>
```

css

```
/* this line is assumed from bootstrap */
a {text-decoration: none;}
.activePage {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

javascript

```
$('.dropdown-menu a').click(function() {
  $('.dropdown-menu a').removeClass('activePage');
  $(this).addClass('activePage');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the codepen link and the advice. I made the changes, but it still does not work.

Comment: My solution works, each link is underlined when you click it, do you have more code? Are you actually changing URIs and loading a new page when you click links? Because then the JavaScript is loaded again and does not maintain state between page loads. In this case, you will not want to change the active page class using JavaScript, but possibly hardcode it in the HTML.

Comment: Thanks Alex, after writing some more code and actually linking the webpages to each other, I realized that my code won't work.  I have figured out how to do this on loading each new page. But regardless, thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You typed `.dropdown-menu .a` instead of `.dropdown-menu a`.

It will not work

```
$('.dropdown-menu .a').click(function(){
     $('.dropdown-menu .a').removeClass('activePage');
     $(this).addClass('activePage');
}
```

It Will Work

```
$('.dropdown-menu a').click(function(){
     $('.dropdown-menu a').removeClass('activePage');
     $(this).addClass('activePage');
}
```